# Co-Host Ruby on Rails and another web application

Tags: java, .net, ruby-on-rails, web-services, hosting

I have a rest web service based on **Rails**.I have another 3rd party website that will be built on either *java or .Net*. I wanted **both the applications** i.e. my rails web service and the third party web application that is built on java or .Net to **share the database**.So we are planning to **host both the applications on the same server**.Is this possible and what are the **hosting providers** that have this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you will find an option for a shared host on which you can do both natively, but you could easily do both on almost any VPS or cloud hosting option.

The other reasonable option I think would be to find a Java Servlet host (Tomcat host) and run your Rails application under JRuby. There is pretty good support for this option and it is fairly mature (I could not say the same of IronRuby).

Answer (score 1):

Both applications run on Windows, so should run on the same server.

So either look for hosting providers that support both applications or get a Virtual Private Server (VPS) and install the software yourself.

Comment: @Jeremy: If it was a java and .Net app that needed to be co hosted do we have more options?